# Distance between footnote index and the following text

Tags: spacing, footnotes

I'm having a problem with my footnotes. The problem is that the distance between the footnote index in the main text and the following text is huge. There are several threads on this and similar topics, but none of the solutions help me. The reason is presumably that I have added something to the preamble (based on an earlier problem I had) to get arabic numerals for examples in the footnotes. In the following preamble, if I remove everything from  \makeatletter downwards, the problem disappears, but I no longer get arabic numerals in my examples in the footnote. So, I want to keep the arabic numerals in the footnotes, and reduce the spacing between the footnote index in the main text and the following text to what is normal. Any ideas?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath
 \let\eachwordone\itshape

 \makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@footnotetext}{
    \@noftnotefalse\setcounter{fnx}{0}%
    \renewcommand{\thexnumi}{\roman{xnumi}}
    }{}{}
\apptocmd{\@footnotetext}{
    \@noftnotetrue
    \renewcommand{\thexnumi}{\arabic{xnumi}}
    }{}{}
\@ifpackageloaded{bidi}{%
\pretocmd{\@LTRfootnotetext}{
    \@noftnotefalse\setcounter{fnx}{0}%
    \renewcommand{\thexnumi}{\roman{xnumi}}
    }{}{}
\apptocmd{\@LTRfootnotetext}{
    \@noftnotetrue
    \renewcommand{\thexnumi}{\arabic{xnumi}}
    }{}{}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text.\footnote{Some text. \begin{exe} \ex  Arabic numerals. \end{exe}} WHY IS THIS TEXT SO FAR REMOVED?


\end{document}
```

Comment: You are missing a few `%` at the end of lines in your `\makeatletter...\makeatother` block. In particular you need a `%` after each `\renewcommand{\thexnumi}{\roman{xnumi}}` and after each `pretocmd{\@footnotetext}{`/`apptocmd{\@footnotetext}{`.

Comment: @moewe, thanks, I added those, but I didn't really change anything with regards to the problem...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/moewew/cd0bd0ffe1b195f3c886e74d346e5055 works for me. What did you try and what output do you get? (Screenshot after you added the `%`.)

Comment: @moewe, I just copied and pasted your part from "makeatletter" to "makeatother" into the preamble, and now it works for me as well. Clearly there was some minor detail that was wrong somewhere. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I guess your question is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864 then. I voted as such.